# Подготовка данных для обучения модели по методу опорных векторов

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Пытаюсь подготовить данные к обучению по методу опорных векторов, но почему-то появляется следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/mashin_learn/3_week/main.py", line 8, in <module>
y = data[:1,:]
File "D:\mashin_learn\3_week\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "D:\mashin_learn\3_week\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 75, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
TypeError: '(slice(None, 1, None), slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key
```

Вот данные с которыми я работаю:

```
   0.0   0.7  0.29
0  1.0  0.23  0.55
1  0.0  0.72  0.42
2  0.0  0.98  0.68
3  0.0  0.48  0.39
4  1.0  0.34  0.73
5  0.0  0.44  0.06
6  1.0  0.40  0.74
7  0.0  0.18  0.18
8  1.0  0.53  0.53
```

А это код:

```
import pandas
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.svm import SVC

data = pandas.read_csv('svm-data.csv')
print(data)

x = data[:0]
y = data[:1,:]
```

Не могли бы вы подсказать, что я не так делаю и где можно посмотреть необходимую документацию?

Comment: в каком столбце у вас результат (`y`) - в первом? в последнем?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Ошибку `TypeError: '(slice(None, 1, None), slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key` вызывает строка:

```
y = data[:1,:]
```

Если вы имеете ввиду срез без заголовка, попробуйте:

```
y = data[1:]
```

ps про срезы в [python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_slice.asp) и в [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по примеру данных из вопроса, в вашем CSV файле отсутствует строка с наименованиями столбцов.

`pd.read_csv()` по умолчанию использует первую строку CSV файла как строку с наименованиями столбцов. В вашем случае стоит воспользоваться параметром `header=None`:

```
data = pd.read_csv('svm-data.csv', header=None)
```

тогда DataFrame будеи выглядеть так (обратите внимание на названия столбцов):

```
     0     1     2
0  0.0  0.70  0.29
1  1.0  0.23  0.55
2  0.0  0.72  0.42
3  0.0  0.98  0.68
4  0.0  0.48  0.39
5  1.0  0.34  0.73
6  0.0  0.44  0.06
7  1.0  0.40  0.74
8  0.0  0.18  0.18
9  1.0  0.53  0.53
```

после этого к столбцам можно обращаться по наименованиям - `data[0]`, `data[1]`, etc.

---

Вторая ошибка в том, что вы неправильно обращаетесь к столбцам по их порядковому номеру - правильно это делается так:

```
y = data.iloc[:, 0] # первый столбец
```

или так:

```
y = data.iloc[:, -1] # последний столбец
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых у вас похоже первая строка данных попала в заголовок таблицы. Это лечится с помощью задания ключей при чтении `csv`, возможно вам нужно указать `header=None`.

Во-вторых, вы что-то странное пытаетесь получить в `x` и `y`. Скорее всего вам в `x` нужны все колонки кроме последней, а в `y` - последняя колонка. Тогда это можно сделать так:

```
x = data.iloc[:,:2]
y = data.iloc[:,2]
```

Обязательно нужно использовать `.iloc`, если вы делаете срезы по абсолютным номерам колонок/строк. И первая компонента среза отвечает за строки (я задал, что нужны все строки с помощью `:`), вторая компонента - за столбцы (соответственно, в `x` попадут все столбцы с `0` до `1`, а в `y` - столбец `2`).

Comment: почти одновременно )

Comment: @MaxU Но вы были таки быстрее. А так да )  Хорошо хоть не дословно ответы совпали ))